Delete div and label for that div without label id
Using Crispy forms in Django app, I the HTML code:
<div id="div_id_pripadnost" class="form-group"> <label for="id_pripadnost_0" class="">
               Pripadnost
           </label> 
<div class="">
<div class="form-check"> <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pripadnost" id="id_pripadnost_1" value=""> <label for="id_pripadnost_1" class="form-check-label">
           ---------
       </label> </div>
<div class="form-check"> <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked="checked" name="pripadnost" id="id_pripadnost_2" value="CRS"> <label for="id_pripadnost_2" class="form-check-label">
           CRS
       </label> </div>
<div class="form-check"> <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pripadnost" id="id_pripadnost_3" value="SCM"> <label for="id_pripadnost_3" class="form-check-label">
           SCM
       </label>
</div> </div> </div>

I would like to remove div with id="id_pripadnost_1". I have removed radio button/div "form-check", but I can't remove label '---------', since it doesn't have an id. How can you remove that label?
I have tried:
            const radioBtn = document.getElementById('id_pripadnost_1');
            radioBtn.style.display = 'none';
            radioBtn.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'none';

            document.getElementById('id_pripadnost_1').remove();


Perhaps try to prevent rendering it in the first place. Can you show the Model(Form) that generates the HTML form?

I can't prevent, since I need it, and depending on other options I'll hide/show it.

Haven't tested it, but can you target the label with querySelector?  So, document.querySelector('label[for="id_pripadnost_1"]').remove();

Worked like a charm. Thank you!

If you really want to remove the div itself, not just its children, then you can do this in one JS remove by using CSS :has.


<div id="div_id_pripadnost" class="form-group"> <label for="id_pripadnost_0" class="">
               Pripadnost
           </label>
  <div class="">
    <div class="form-check"> <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pripadnost" id="id_pripadnost_1" value=""> <label for="id_pripadnost_1" class="form-check-label">
           ---------
       </label> </div>
    <div class="form-check"> <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked="checked" name="pripadnost" id="id_pripadnost_2" value="CRS"> <label for="id_pripadnost_2" class="form-check-label">
           CRS
       </label> </div>
    <div class="form-check"> <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="pripadnost" id="id_pripadnost_3" value="SCM"> <label for="id_pripadnost_3" class="form-check-label">
           SCM
       </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  const div = document.querySelector('.form-check:has(#id_pripadnost_1)');
  div.remove();
</script>



